# Typical problem on P with conditions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am looking for prime $p$ greater than or equal to $3$ such that $p|y^2 + 4$ as well as $4|p-3$. I need simple discussion to conclude the existence of $p$.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there were such a $y$, then the congruence $z^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ would have a solution. (Multiply $y$ by the inverse of $2$ modulo $p$.)

But it is a standard fact that if $4$ divides $p-3$, then $-1$ cannot be a quadratic residue of $p$.

Comment: Nicolas! can you go in reverse sir. I mean, consider such z exists and show me what will happen.

Comment: There is no such $p$, the above answer proves that. The fact that $-1$ is not a quadratic residue of a prime congruent to $3$ modulo $4$ is a basic early fact of number theory. Any $z$ such that $z^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ has order $4$ modulo $p$. That implies that $4$ divides $p-1$, which is not true for primes of the form $4k+3$.